# rgb of an image

Tags: matlab

To get RGB values:

```
RGB = imread('C:\Documents and Settings\student2\Desktop\Water lilies.jpg');
R = RGB(:, :, 1);
G = RGB(:, :, 2);
B = RGB(:, :, 3);
```

Can someone tell me why we use 1, 2, and 3 to get Red, Green, and Blue matrices respectively?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the 3 dimensions of an RGB image in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612113/what-are-the-3-dimensions-of-an-rgb-image-in-matlab)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the size of RBG: `size(RGB)`, you will see that it is width X height X 3. Each pixel is represented by 3 values - red, green, and blue; the actual colour of the pixel is a mixture of these primary colour - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model).

If you want to know the reason why R is 1, G is 2 and B is 3, rather than R being 3 and B being 1 or something, it is just convention. I assume because red light is a lower frequency of light, blue is higher and green is in between - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_spectrum).