# What does a m*n*3 matric signify?

Tags: matlab, sign

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the 3 dimensions of an RGB image in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612113/what-are-the-3-dimensions-of-an-rgb-image-in-matlab)

in matlab my colored images are in the form of a m*n*3 matrix form, what does the 3 dimension signify?
will i lose any data if u skip the third dimension?

as far as i reason, at the coordinates m,n the value is a pixel, what is the third dimension for?

For example is

```
B(1,2,3)=B(1,2)
```

???

Comment: Probably one dimension per color channel in the image....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third dimension is the color channel. It stands for Red,Green and Blue.

B(1,2,3) is the blue channel of the pixel located at row 1, column 2.

Answer (score 0):

It's color! In the form of triplets representing each color's intensity (R,G,B).  If you skip the third dimension, you picture will only display shades of one color channel -- red, I think.

Comment: Well, it will be the information from the red channel, BUT the picture will display in shades of GRAY, not red.