# How to sort this error out_the 'RGB_image' parameter must be a 3-dimensional array

Tags: r, arrays, image, image-processing, grayscale

#packages

```
     library(abind)

     library(openImageR)
```

#this code load the data

```
     path = list.files("../df",".jpg", full.names = T)
```

#read the data

```
imgs=lapply(path, readImage)
```

#this binds the data as an array

```
comb <- do.call(abind,c(imgs,list(along =3)))
```

#the output of the above is 480X640X18 for six images

#this code is to convert images to grascale

#but it does not work it gives an error

#the error: The 'RGB_image' parameter must be a 3-dimensional

```
 df<-rgb_2gray(comb)
```

Comment: In the next days I'll modify the error messages of the [OpenImageR package](https://github.com/mlampros/OpenImageR) because the current ones might not return the exact requirements for an input image. If you receive this error then the image has to be 3-dimensional and the 3rd dimension should be equal to 3 (for instance an RGB image of dimensions 480 x 640 x 3)

Comment: @lampros it works if I loaded one image and make it 480X640 and I think it should be 480X640X1 instead, but it does not work for a list of images, and the outcome should be 480X640X10 (number of total images) not 480X640X30 when the images 'rgb' shape

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @user20003920 [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612130/8302386) might help you understand what the depth of an RGB image is.

Comment: @lampros I know these differences and that's why I want convert my images into grayscale. Have you finished the amendments of the package?

Comment: @lampros if not yet, do you know another way that converts my images into grayscale?

Comment: @Robert Hacken sorry for tagging but I've seen answering many questions related to arrays. Do you have any idea how to convert a list of images from 3 channels into one channel in r?